# How do I get an aggregate of aggregate on tableau?

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api

I have amount spent aggregated by 'account id' on different product 'categories':

Categories: A, B, C; Account IDs: 101, 102, 103..

101 A $12
101 B $13
101 C $11
102 A $11
102 B $13
103 A $15
103 C $11

I wish to have the average spend per user/account in Tableau:
101 $12
102 $12
103 $13

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First account id needs to be dragged into dimension shelf.
To take the aggregate of price by account id. Just drag the account id and price to the rows shelf. Price will be summed up automatically. Double click the sum and change it into avg.